# How to concatenate two bigint values in hive while loading to another table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have columns A and B as bigint in the table yyy. I am trying to load the table yyy to zzz.

```
INSERT into TABLE zzz PARTITION (date_key)
SELECT * ,
concat(A,'-',B) AS VISITOR,
FROM yyy;
```

In DDL of zzz table, visitor column is represented as bigint.
But I am getting the result as NULL values in the visitor column.

Comment: What makes you think you can store a string (`...someting...-...somthing...`) as a bigint?

Comment: Assuming A=12 and B=345, you are trying to store the string `'12-345'` as bigint. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: this is my requirement to concatenate two columns as one column. would making visitor column as string solve the problem?

Comment: Do you see that something is wrong here?

Comment: modifying visitor column as string solve the problem?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: thanks. it solves the issue.